# Class and object error

Tags: python

I am using a book to learn programming and I started learning about objects and classes. I created my class:

```
class Giraffes:
    def __init__(self, spots):
        self.giraffe_spots = spots
```

I then created Ozwald with a number for his spots:

```
ozwald = Giraffes(75)
```

It then gives me an error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    ozwald = Giraffes(75)
 File "<pyshell#3>", line 3, in __init__
   self.giraffe_spots = spot
NameError: name 'spot' is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong? I've done exactly what my book is telling me to do.

Comment: this error message does not come from that code. there was an 's' missing in the original code (spot vs spots) and you must have fixed it. see the line where it tells you `self.giraffe_spots = spot`, it is not the same line that you posted

Comment: @JulienSpronck Where?

Comment: `self.giraffe_spots = spot` should be `self.giraffe_spots = spots`

Comment: @Marcin Oooooohhhhhh. Well now I feel stupid . Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
self.giraffe_spots = spots
```

is written as this:

```
self.giraffe_spots = spot
```

wherever you are actually running it.